# Can't compile any Qt projects in Windows commandline, only in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, msvc12

I'm starting to mess with Qt, and I've had no issues compiling projects within their IDE. Commandline has been a different story. Qt Creator is cool and all, but I need to automate my builds.

It doesn't get much more simple than this:

**untitled.pro** contents:

```
SOURCES += \
    source.cpp
```

**source.cpp** contents:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

In the compile output, it's apparently doing this:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1_x64\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
```

So, I open CMD.exe, and run the following:

```
C:\MyProjectDir>C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1_x64\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\qmake.exe
```

That made my debug, release, .qmake.stash, Makefile, Makefile.Debug, and Makefile.Release files and directories.

Next, I ran:

```
C:\MyProjectDir>C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1_x64\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
```

And I'm always getting this error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'shell32.lib' jom:
>   C:\MyProjectDir\Makefile.Debug [debug\untitled.exe] Error 1104

What am I doing wrong? I also gave nmake a shot, but that didn't work either. I'd rather use jom.

For this specific project, it's using the msvc2013_64-5.5.1 pre-comp'd installer

Edit: Since nmake was mentioned in the comments, here is the error output for nmake:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'shell32.lib' NMAKE
>   : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\bin\link.EXE"' : return code '0x49d' Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2' Stop.

Comment: Just type 'make' after executing qmake and that will do the job.

Comment: It doesn't. I explained that at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Have not checked but works fine for me.

Comment: I added my nmake error output.

Comment: Can you please update your complete ,pro file

Comment: Nothing has changed o.0 Those are the only two files, and that is all of their content. I think I misunderstood you.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck did you try with the Qt command line shortcut ?

Comment: @Ilya No. I did exactly what was stated in the question, no more, no less. CMD->Qmake->Jom|nmake    Where is this shortcut, and what is it called?

Comment: It's installed with Qt Creator, look in the start menu "Qt 5.x for desktop..."

Comment: I belive you will have 3 files called Makefile, Makefile.Debug, makefile.Release...Right

Comment: @SudiptaKumarSahoo yes, as stated in the question above, "That made my debug, release, .qmake.stash, Makefile, Makefile.Debug, and Makefile.Release files and directories."    -- Removing the old files and re-running qmake didn't resolve any issues.

Comment: @Ilya So, using that shortcut + following its instructions at the top, "Setting up environment for Qt usage...
Remember to call vcvarsall.bat to complete environment setup!" solved it! TYVM!!!

Comment: As a side note in Ubuntu (or in Linux generally) you don't need to setup anything if Qt tools are installed from the package repositories. Everything works also in the command line out-of-the-box. This question is a perfect example why I prefer Ubuntu in Qt development.

Comment: I didn't really have a problem with Qt Creator for Windows, but dang, this was a headache. Good to know about Ubuntu, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (or imitate) the Qt command prompt ("Qt 5.x for desktop..." shortcut), it'll have the PATH you need set.

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone checking this, that CMD shortcut was here for me, just update the qt program name for whatever you gave it. I didn't want the default name `Qt 5.5.1` as I have multiple 5.5.1 installations: `"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Qt 5.5.1_x64\5.5\MSVC 2013 (64-bit)"`

Comment: To not screw around with the shortcut, use the Target shown in the shortcut's properties. For me, that was: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /A /Q /K C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1_x64\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\qtenv2.bat` and `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1_x64` was what I called the directory for my qt installation -- I think it defaults to `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1`

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck before Win8 the shortcut was easier to spot I think (alongside Qt Creator in the Start menu). Perhaps it's easier (again) on Win10, what Windows version are you using ?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: So, in Windows 10, when I check Qt folders, I don't get the CMD shortcut, but things like Linguist and Designer show up -- I right-clicked those and chose "Open file location", and they share the same file location as the cmd shortcut.